# The Remote server returned an error: 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, .net

My Org has this web app built using .net framework 4.8.1, It gives uploads a file on the azure storage account and downloads it. I am facing this error while downloading the file :
[Error Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpEpX.png)

I have a AzureStorageHelper class that helps in creating and deleting blob containers

The Code for the Azure Storage Helper :

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using ExportToPPT.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
namespace ExportToPPT.Helpers
{

    public class AzureStorageHelper
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        CloudBlobClient blobClient;
        CloudBlobContainer container;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor Initialize AzureStorageHelper
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="storageKey">string</param>
        /// <param name="containerPath">string</param>
        public AzureStorageHelper(string storageKey, string containerPath)
        {
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageKey);
            blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerPath);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to upload file to mentioned Azure Storage Blob
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name = "filePath" >Local path of the file to be uploaded to Blob Storage</ param >
        /// <param name="blobPath">The name of the file to be uploaded</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void DownloadFile(string filePath, string blobPath)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobPath);
            /// blockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew);
            blockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// deletes the container if it exists
        /// </summary>
        public void DeleteContainer()
        {
            container.DeleteIfExists();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// creates a new container
        /// </summary>
        public void CreateContainer()
        {
            container.Create();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to download file from Azure Blob Storage
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name = "filePath" >Local path of the file to be downloaded to Blob Storage</ param >
        /// <param name="blobPath">The name of the file to be downloaded on Azure Blob Storage</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void UploadFile(string filePath, string blobPath)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobPath);
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";

            using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
            }
        }

        public List<string> getFiles()
        {
            try
            {
                var list = container.ListBlobs();
                //List<string> blobNames = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
                List<string> blobNames = list.Select(b => (b as CloudBlockBlob).Name).ToList();
                return blobNames;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public List<Account> getAccounts()
        {
            IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> list = container.ListBlobs();
            IListBlobItem[] blobAccounts = list.ToArray();
            CloudBlockBlob blobAccount = null;
            List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
            Account account = null;
            string daysText = string.Empty;
            foreach (IListBlobItem blob in blobAccounts)
            {
                blobAccount = blob as CloudBlockBlob;
                account = new Account();
                account.EmailId = blobAccount.Name;
                account.CreatedDate = blobAccount.Properties.Created;
                daysText = blobAccount.DownloadText();
                int.TryParse(daysText, out account.TrialDays);
                account.ExpiryDate = account.CreatedDate.Value.AddDays(account.TrialDays);
                account.isExpired = true;
                if (System.DateTimeOffset.Now < account.ExpiryDate)
                {
                    account.isExpired = false;
                }

                accounts.Add(account);
            }

            return accounts;
        }
        public bool isAuthenticated(string emailId)
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = false;
            try
            {
                var list = container.ListBlobs();
                IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = list.Where(b => (b as CloudBlockBlob).Name.Contains(emailId));
                if (blobs.Count() > 0)
                {
                    IListBlobItem genericBlob = blobs.OrderByDescending(b => (b as CloudBlockBlob).Properties.LastModified).First();
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)genericBlob;
                    DateTimeOffset? lastModifiedDate = blob.Properties.LastModified;
                    string name = blob.Name;
                    if (lastModifiedDate == null)
                    {
                        lastModifiedDate = blob.Properties.Created;
                    }

                    string text = blob.DownloadText();
                    int days = 0;
                    int.TryParse(text, out days);

                    if (System.DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays((days * (-1))) < lastModifiedDate)
                    {
                        isAuthenticated = true;
                    }
                };

                return isAuthenticated;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return isAuthenticated;
            }
        }
    }
```

The Controller file that uses this class for blob container management ExportController code :

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Lambda;
using Amazon.Lambda.Model;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using ExportToPPT.Helpers;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;  // for class Encoding
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace ExportToPPT.Controllers
{
    public class ExportController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// creates azure container and uploads custom ppt if user has uploaded one
        /// triggers external puppeteer(node) api to generate screenshot and sends response back to frontend
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accessToken"></param>
        /// <param name="emailId"></param>
        /// <param name="guidString"></param>
        /// <param name="InfoText"></param>
        /// <param name="isCustomTemplate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>      
        public JsonResult ExportPPT(string accessToken, string emailId, string guidString, string infoText, bool isCustomTemplate, string mode)
        {
            string jsonStringForPPTApp = string.Empty;
            string pptName = "";

            if (mode == "ppt")
            {
                pptName = guidString + ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.pptExtension;
            }
            else if (mode == "pdf")
            {
                pptName = guidString + ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.pdfExtension;
            }

            string pptPath = Path.Combine(ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.sessionFolder, guidString, pptName);

            //upload custom template to blob
            try
            {
                AzureStorageHelper blob = new AzureStorageHelper(ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.blobConnectionString, guidString);

                //create container
                blob.CreateContainer();

                //uploading ppt
                if (isCustomTemplate)
                {
                    blob.UploadFile(pptPath, pptName);
                }

                //trigger puppeteer to take screenshot
                string awsAccessKeyID = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.awsAccessKey;
                string awsSecretKeyID = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.awsSecretKey;

                //creates object for a particular region of aws
                AmazonLambdaConfig config = new AmazonLambdaConfig() { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1 };
                AmazonLambdaClient amazonClient = new AmazonLambdaClient(awsAccessKeyID, awsSecretKeyID, config);

                //defines parameter for function to be executed 
                InvokeRequest invokeReq = new InvokeRequest()
                {
                    FunctionName = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.awsFunctionName,
                    Payload = infoText
                };

                // invoke Lambda function asyncronously so we do not wait for it's results
                amazonClient.InvokeAsync(invokeReq);
                
                JObject informationData = JObject.Parse(infoText);
                var NoOfSlides = informationData["Visuals"].Values();
                var slides = informationData["visuals"].Children();
                int noOfSlides = 0;
                int noOfVisuals = 0;
                foreach (var slide in slides)
                {
                    noOfSlides++;
                    JArray visuals = (JArray)slide.First;
                    noOfVisuals += visuals.Count;
                }

                TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
                client.Context.User.Id = emailId;
                client.Context.Session.Id = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
                client.Context.Properties.Add("Guid", guidString);
                client.Context.Properties.Add("NoOfVisuals", noOfVisuals.ToString());
                client.Context.Properties.Add("NoOfSlides", noOfSlides.ToString());
                client.Context.Properties.Add("IsCustomTemplate", isCustomTemplate.ToString());

                client.TrackPageView("Export");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.webLogLocation))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.webLogLocation);
                }

                string logFile = string.Format("{0}{1}.csv", ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.webLogLocation, guidString);
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logFile, "Export function exception " + exception.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);

                //return error of screenshot utility
                return Json("Screenshot Error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json(jsonStringForPPTApp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Download PowerPoint file for given guid, if PPT is not present return error PPT
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="guid"></param>
        /// <returns>PowerPoint file</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Export/DownloadPPT/{guid}/{mode}")]
        public void DownloadPPT(string guid, string mode)
        {
            string currentDirectory = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.sessionFolder;
            string pptFileName = "";

            if (mode == "ppt")
            {
                pptFileName = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.updatedPPTFileName + guid + ".pptx";
            }
            else if (mode == "pdf")
            {
                pptFileName = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.updatedPDFFileName + guid + ".pdf";
            }
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, pptFileName);

            string filePathParent = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, guid);

            if (!Directory.Exists(filePathParent))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathParent);
            }

            string blobFileName = pptFileName;

            byte[] fstream = new byte[0];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            HttpContext currentRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            string blobConnectionString = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.blobConnectionString;
            AzureStorageHelper blob = null;
            try
            {
                bool notErrorPPTCheck = false;
                currentRequest.Response.Clear();
                try
                {
                    blob = new AzureStorageHelper(blobConnectionString, guid);
                    blob.DownloadFile(filePath, blobFileName);
                    notErrorPPTCheck = true;

                }
                catch
                {
                    blob = new AzureStorageHelper(blobConnectionString, ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.blobStaticAssets);
                    blob.DownloadFile(filePath, ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.errorPPTName);
                }
                string failedPPTPath = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.errorFilePath;
                string failedPDFPath = ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.errorPDFPath;

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    }
                    if (mode == "ppt")
                    {
                        currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.updatedPPTFileName + " - " + DateTime.Now + ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.updatedPPTFileNameExtension);
                    }
                    else if (mode == "pdf")
                    {
                        currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.updatedPDFFileName + " - " + DateTime.Now + ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.updatedPDFFileNameExtension);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mode == "ppt" && System.IO.File.Exists(failedPPTPath))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(failedPPTPath, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        }
                        currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Error.pptx");
                    }
                    else if(mode == "pdf" && System.IO.File.Exists(failedPDFPath))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(failedPDFPath, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
                        }
                        currentRequest.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Error.pdf");
                    }
                }
                if (mode == "ppt")
                {
                    currentRequest.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
                }
                else if (mode == "pdf")
                {
                    currentRequest.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                }

                currentRequest.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
                currentRequest.Response.Flush();
                currentRequest.Response.Close();

                //delete blob container containing images and pptx
                blob.DeleteContainer();

                //delete downloaded ppt
                Directory.Delete(filePathParent, true);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.webLogLocation))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.webLogLocation);
                }

                string logFile = string.Format("{0}{1}.csv", ExportToPPT.Common.Constants.webLogLocation, guid);
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logFile, "DownloadPPT exception " + exception.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
                throw exception;
            }
        }
```

The error is thrown at blob.DownloadFile(filePath, blobFileName); line in the DownlaodPPT function

I tried writing the AzureStorageHelper class using the package Azure.Storage.Common but then too getting an error at the download part. The code is as follows :

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using ExportToPPT.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
namespace ExportToPPT.Helpers
{

    public class AzureStorageHelper
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;
        BlobContainerClient containerClient;

        public AzureStorageHelper(string connectionString, string containerName)
        {
            blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        }

        public void DownloadFile(string filePath, string blobPath)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobPath);

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            {
                BlobDownloadInfo blobDownloadInfo = blobClient.Download();
                blobDownloadInfo.Content.CopyTo(fs);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        public void DeleteContainer()
        {
            containerClient.DeleteIfExists();
        }

        public void CreateContainer()
        {
            containerClient.Create();
        }

        public void UploadFile(string filePath, string blobPath)
        {
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobPath);
            blobClient.Upload(filePath, true);
        }

        public List<string> getFiles()
        {
            var blobItems = containerClient.GetBlobs();
            return blobItems.Select(blob => blob.Name).ToList();
        }

        public List<Account> getAccounts()
        {
            var blobItems = containerClient.GetBlobs();
            List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

            foreach (var blobItem in blobItems)
            {
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
                Account account = new Account();
                account.EmailId = blobItem.Name;
                account.CreatedDate = blobItem.Properties.CreatedOn;

                string daysText = blobClient.DownloadContent().ToString();
                int.TryParse(daysText, out account.TrialDays);

                account.ExpiryDate = account.CreatedDate.Value.AddDays(account.TrialDays);
                account.isExpired = DateTimeOffset.Now >= account.ExpiryDate;

                accounts.Add(account);
            }

            return accounts;
        }

        public bool isAuthenticated(string emailId)
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = false;

            try
            {
                var blobItems = containerClient.GetBlobs();
                var matchingBlobs = blobItems.Where(blob => blob.Name.Contains(emailId));

                if (matchingBlobs.Any())
                {
                    var latestBlob = matchingBlobs.OrderByDescending(blob => blob.Properties.LastModified).First();
                    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(latestBlob.Name);

                    DateTimeOffset? lastModifiedDate = latestBlob.Properties.LastModified;
                    if (lastModifiedDate == null)
                    {
                        lastModifiedDate = latestBlob.Properties.CreatedOn;
                    }

                    string text = blobClient.DownloadContent().ToString();
                    int days = 0;
                    int.TryParse(text, out days);

                    isAuthenticated = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-days) < lastModifiedDate;
                }

                return isAuthenticated;
            }
            catch (Exception exceptionObj)
            {
                return isAuthenticated;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to correct such errors